# My MP3 file is blocked, but still playable?

Tags: windows, file-types, file-access, windows-vista

My computer is telling me that my MP3 file is blocked:

[image]

I have no problems playing the song, so I was wondering what exactly does it mean for my MP3 file to be blocked?

Comment: Do you have a specific security concern: is this a vulnerability, does it increase your exposure exposure,?

Comment: @this.josh I mean this is whta I meant.. is this file a vulnerability? does it increase my exposure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screenshot indicates that the Windows Attachment Manager has identified what it considers a possibly dangerous file from an external source and marked it. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883260 for information on what the Attachment Manager is and how to configure it.

The Windows Attachment Manager will mark many types of files that could possibly be a risk (without analysing the content) based on where it originated from. If you are just playing an MP3 you probably didn't even get a warning because of the way you are using the file. However if you had an `.exe` file instead Windows would warn you before it allowed it to run.

The additional stream information that "tags" the file as originating an external source will be copied around with the file in most circumstances (it will not if copied to some file systems such as FAT).

Ideally if you trust the source where the file originated from then you can unblock the file. Otherwise leaving the file blocked will not prevent access to the file however in some circumstances you may be presented with a warning before Windows allows the action.

Hope this helps.